# Can we stand for just one more ordered set puzzle?

Tags: knowledge, history

Actually, probably not. You might want to sit down for this one. I'll try not to ramble. Haven't we done this before? Out with the old, in with the new! Let's go!!

The following is the first 7 numbers in an ordered set:

**1431, 135, 2321, 1730, 2166, 1177, 1211, ...**

What is the next number?

Comment: Question - Are there any clues provided in the question or is it just about guessing?

Comment: Yes I have been adding clues to bring the puzzle in line with the current standards. :)

Comment: Sorry about all the edits. I am happy with the clues I have in there now. Next time, I'll try to get it right before posting!!

Comment: The Langrage Interpolation gives (surprisingly) a whole number - 48247. The polynomial: $p(x)=\frac{5495x^6}{144}−\frac{224963x^5}{240}+\frac{1315745x^4}{144}−\frac{2152453x^3}{48}+\frac{2074405x^2}{18}−\frac{8612033x}{60}+66325$

Comment: @boboquack Wow that was elaborate! However, note the lack of the mathematics tag. No calculator needed to solve this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next Number is

> 3375

Reason

> These are number of words spoken in each of the presidential innaugrations in US. Here is a [complete list](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/inaugurals.php)

Comment: Very well done! :)

Comment: No problems. Though, this was too trivial. Being a non american myself, I am not sure if its even possible to crack. It was just that I have been lurking into these kind of things recently.

Comment: Yeah I thought with the inauguration coming up, it would be timely. I should have included the trivia tag, I suppose.